# Best way to get a sub-path of a file

Tags: java

I have two `File` objects:

1. C:/basepath/
2. C:/basepath/directory/file.txt

Now I would like to subtract file 1 from file 2 so that I get `directory/file.txt`.
I don't want to use `String.substring()` since file paths may differ from input.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the features of `java.nio.file.Path`. You are looking to 'relativize'.